# Replacing hard-coded contiguous cells with a loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This task concerns Google Sheets and a Google Apps Scripts I wrote.

There is a task: we have a table which consists of 1 colomn and 3 rows. Each row (which is a cell also) contains a record of the following type "4d 1a 3c 5e 2b", where each letter can be subsituted by a word. In each row (cell) expressions may or may not repeat the "4d 1a 3c 5e 2b" expression, the distribution of numbers is random.

I need to do the following thing - divide each cell with "4d 1a 3c 5e 2b" type expression into 5 separate cells, sort them in ascending order.

On the one hand, I solved this problem. Firstly I created a variable and assigned the expression from the cell as a value to it. Then I created an array by means of `.split(" ")` method and sorted the items of the array by `.sort()` method. As a result I managed to set the values, which were items of sorted array, for a few cells.

Here is the code:

```
function mySort() {
  var dt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("F3").getValue();
  var arr = dt.split(" ");
  a = arr.sort();
  var first = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("H3").setValue(arr[0]);
  var second = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("I3").setValue(arr[1]);
  var third =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("J3").setValue(arr[2]);

  var ddt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("F4").getValue();
  var arr2 = ddt.split(" ");
  aa = arr2.sort();
  var first2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("H4").setValue(arr2[0]);
  var second2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("I4").setValue(arr2[1]);
  var third2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("J4").setValue(arr2[2]);

  var dddt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("F5").getValue();
  var arr3 = dddt.split(" ");
  aa = arr3.sort();
  var first3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("H5").setValue(arr3[0]);
  var second3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("I5").setValue(arr3[1]);
  var third3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myPage").getRange("J5").setValue(arr3[2]);
}
```

As you can see, everything works: when I push the button with `mySort()` function assigned I get an appropriate result. However, I would like do more. It would be great if I could select as many rows as I want, then push the button and see how the loop goes through all the rows, splits them, sorts them, and assigns the elements of each sorted array to the cells next to the initial cell. To make it more clear, the final result must look something like this:

"4d 1a 3c 5e 2b" /// "1a" "2b" "3c" "4d" "5e"

"1g 5i 2g 4f 3h" /// "1g" "2g" "3h" "4f" "5i"

"5n 3m 1l 4k 2o" /// "1l" "2o" "3m" "4k" "5n"

So, how can I use loop in Google Sheets which will do such thing without typing in which exactly cell I want to see the items of the sorted array?

Comment: look at `Sheet#getActiveRange`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you.

```
function yourSort(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('myPage');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=2;i<vA.values();i++){
    var A=String(vA[i][5]).split(" ").sort();
    vA[i][7]=A[0];
    vA[i][8]=A[1];
    vA[i][9]=A[2];
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

As long as you have headers for every column and some data on every row then I think getDataRange() will work for you.

Comment: in the `for` loop it should be `i = 1` if there is 1 header row and `i = 0` if there are no header rows.

Comment: The data in the example starts in row 3.